# BizTalk and Custom Binding and disable receive location

Tags: c#, binding, biztalk

I've create a custom binding (System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding) for BizTalk based on RabbitMQ.ServiceModel

https://github.com/CymaticLabs/Unity3D.Amqp/tree/master/lib/rabbitmq-dotnet-client-rabbitmq_v3_4_4/projects/wcf/RabbitMQ.ServiceModel/src/serviceModel

I'm trying to disable my receive location when the queue does not exist.
I Can detect that the queue is missing in the `public override void Open(TimeSpan timeout)` in `RabbitMQInputChannel.cs`, but I don't know how to disable my receive location.

https://github.com/CymaticLabs/Unity3D.Amqp/blob/master/lib/rabbitmq-dotnet-client-rabbitmq_v3_4_4/projects/wcf/RabbitMQ.ServiceModel/src/serviceModel/RabbitMQInputChannel.cs

```
    namespace RabbitMQ.ServiceModel
    {
        internal sealed class RabbitMQInputChannel : RabbitMQInputChannelBase // Implement interface IChannel and IInputChannel
        {
            [...]

            public override void Open(TimeSpan timeout)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (State != CommunicationState.Created && State != CommunicationState.Closed)
                    {
                        this.Close();
                        throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("Cannot open the channel from the {0} state.", base.State));
                    }
                    OnOpening();

                    string queueName = m_bindingElement.QueueName;
                    string key = m_bindingElement.RoutingKey == null ? string.Empty : m_bindingElement.RoutingKey;
                    string exchange = m_bindingElement.ExchangeName;


                    if (m_bindingElement.QueueDeclare)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            m_model.QueueDeclare(queueName, true, false, false, null);
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {

                        }
                    }


                    //Listen to the queue
                    m_consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(m_model);
                    m_consumer.ConsumerCancelled += OnConsumerCancelled;
                    m_consumer.Received += (sender, args) => m_queue.Add(args);
                    m_model.BasicConsume(queueName, false, m_consumer);

                    OnOpened();


                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    EventLogHelper.WriteError(ex.Message);
                    this.Close();
                }
            }

            private void OnConsumerCancelled(object sender, ConsumerEventArgs e)
            {
                // HERE I WANT TO DISABLE MY RECEIVE LOCATION

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing is to enable the [DisableLocationOnFailure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/wcf.disablelocationonfailure?view=bts-dotnet) property on your WCF-Custom Receive Location.

Then you need to throw an exception in the method [IInputChannel.TryReceive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.channels.iinputchannel.tryreceive?view=netframework-4.6) when the queue is missing.

Comment: That don't work.  TryReceive is only called when a message has been posted in the queue, not when the queue has been deleted

Comment: What about IInputChannel.BeginWaitForMessage